# Xmodmap: Assign right ctrl to two keys

Tags: xmodmap

I'm trying to use right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to type `->`

Is that possible? If not, do you know of an easy way to achieve it?

Here's the code I tried:

```
keycode 105 = (minus, greater)
```

Comment: Found a solution by creating a global shortcut for this command `xdotool key minus greater`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You can reply your solution as an answer and accept it, for others to benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `xdotool`

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Then assign the following command to a global shortcut

```
xdotool key minus greater
```

You can also change the delay between the two characters (default is 12ms)

```
xdotool key --delay=5 minus greater
```